# VBScript Out Of Memory Error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, out-of-memory

I have a classic ASP CRM that was built by a third party company.  Currently, I have access to the source code and am able to make any changes required.

Randomly throughout the day, usually after some prolonged usage by users, most of my pages start getting an Out of Memory error.

The way that the application is built, is all the pages and scripts pull core functions from a Global.asp file.  In that file are embeds to other global files as well, but the error presented shows

> Out Of Memory
>
> WhateverScriptYouTriedToRun.asp Line 0

Line 0 is the include for the global.asp file.   Once the error occurs, after an unspecified amount of time the error occurence subsides for some time but then begins to reoccur again.  With how the application is written, and the functions it uses, and the "diagnostics" I've already done - it seems to be a common used function that is withholding data such as recordset or something of that nature and then not releasing it properly.  Other users then try to use the same function and eventually it just fills up causing the error. The only way for me to effectively clear the error is to actually restart IIS, Recycle the App Pool, and Restart the SQL Server Services.

Needless to say, myself and my users are getting annoyed....

I can't pinpoint the error due to the actual error message presented being Line 0 - but from there I have no idea where in the 20K lines of code it could be hanging up.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to isolate or at least point me in the right direction to begin clearing this up?  Is there a way for me to increase "memory" size for VBScript?  I know there is a limitation but is it set at say...512K and you can increase it to 1GB?

Here are things I have tried:

1. Removing SQL Inline statements into Views
2. Going through several hundred scripts and ensuring that every OpenConnection & OpenRecordSet is followed by an appropriate Close.
3. Going through the Global File and commenting out any large SQL statements such as ApplicationLog (A function that writes the executed query into a table).
4. Some smaller script edits.

Comment: Further - I do realize that no one answer will solve this and it is relatively difficult for people to guess as to where the problem could lie without knowledge or at least looking at some code.  I'm only asking for some direction and possible "diagnostic" methods I could use.

Comment: I am also receiving HTTP 1.1/500 Error at times during this as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Common Memory Leak**

You say you are closing all recordsets and connections which is good.

But are you deleting objects?

For example:

```
Set adoCon = new
Set rsCommon = new

'Do query stuff

'You do this:
rsCommon.close
adocon.close

'But do you do this?
Set adoCon = nothing
Set rsCommon = nothing
```

No garbage collection in classic ASP, so any objects not destroyed will remain in memory.

Also, ensure your closes/nothings are run in every branch.  For example:

```
adocon.open
rscommon.open etc

'Sql query
myData = rscommon("condition")

if(myData) then
  response.write("ok")
else
  response.redirect("error.asp")
end if

'close
rsCommon.close
adocon.close
Set adoCon = nothing
Set rsCommon = nothing
```

Nothing is closed/destroyed before the redirect so it will only empty memory some of the time as not all branches of logic lead to the proper memory clearance.

**Better Design**

Also unfortunately it sounds like the website wasn't designed well.  I always structure my classic ASP as:

```
<%
    Option Explicit

    'Declare all vars
    Dim this
    Dim that

    'Open connections
    Set adoCon...
    adocon.open()

    'Fetch required data
    rscommon.open strSQL, adoCon
        this = rsCommon.getRows()
    rsCommon.close

    'Fetch something else
    rscommon.open strSQL, adoCon
        that = rsCommon.getRows()
    rsCommon.close

    'Close connections and drop objects
    adoCon.close
    set adoCon = nothing
    set rscommon = nothing

    'Process redirects
    if(condition) then
        response.redirect(url)
    end if
%>
<html>
<body>

<%
    'Use data
    for(i = 0 to ubound(this,2)
        response.write(this(0, i) & " " & this(1, i) & "<br />")
    next
%>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope some of this helped.

Comment: With the garbage collection - what type of information or data is stored as "garbage"? I will have to dig deeper into the global functions to see if they original code is written to destroy garbage. 

I can say....That in the functions I have written, I have not used this - as I wasn't aware you had to do it for ever instance.  I see how it is very helpful and best practice to do so in every case.

I'm not sure I understand your second example.  In my typical code I would have closed connection and RS within the If End If.  Is that the incorrect way?

Comment: @Rogue, see updated answer.  It is better to structure all code this way, then you don't need repeating code for closes, and you can guarantee that everything is closed and destroyed.  Second point was just saying that if the condition is met, it prints "OK" then destroys/closes objects.  If the condition is not met, it redirects the user and DOESNT clean up... memory leak!  You should set obj = nothing to anything that was created with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: @Rogue, also how many recordsets do you have on a normal page?  Using the rs.getRows method to store in an array so you can reuse the same RS over and over again is very good for speed, and makes it harder to forget to close/delete them.

Comment: @Tom - I get what you're saying on the second example.  I reread it lol - thanks.  Again, I'm going to have to review a lot of the scripts to ensure that these procedures are followed. I have a feeling, though, that many - do not follow this.

Comment: In the CloseConnection function, the code does state: If rs.Open then rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing.  The same goes for the RecordSet Function.  So they are cleaning up garbage on the Connections & RecordSets.

Comment: @Rogue, does you site use session variables?  It's pretty rare, but if for some reason someone set these to a ridiculously long expiry, and they hold a lot of data, and you have a high volume of users it could cause these problems.

Comment: There are several Session Variables, although I do not believe they are a huge quantity nor do they store large amounts of data.  Going through some core scripts, I only see about 10 Session Variables being created, and with simply data like Login Name, ID, etc.

Comment: @Rogue, do you know what the expiry on the session variables are?  And is your site a high traffic site?  Also, is your site hosted on a shared server?

Comment: I'm looking into the Expiry.  The site is hosted on an internal server within the company, so it is on my network. There are about 40-60 users who utilize the site currently.

Comment: @Rogue, ok that should all be fine then.  Are there any other scripts/programs running on the server that could be causing this?

Comment: There are other applications that use this server, but none that I would imagine would cause this. I have several SQL Based softwares running, all Windows Applications, nothing that uses IIS.

Comment: @Rogue Are you using any custom VB or C++ COM objects?

Comment: @Rogue some possible KB articles for you to look at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174634/en-gb | http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174685/en-gb | http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191099/en-gb  Most are unlikely but still worth a read just in case

Comment: I've checked those KB articles before - but I cannot find the exact point of fault for some examples so I can rectify.

Comment: On the Session Variable Timeout - it is currently set to 500 (was 200) and Server.ScriptTimeout is 900 and was 600.

Comment: The previous values were commented out next to the current values.

Comment: @Tom - I have been reading different forums etc., and someone had mentioned that ASP will only allow you to run one RecordSet or Query through an open connection. If you attempt to do more than one, it would create more connections automatically - BUT it would not clean them or destroy them appropriately. 

Is this true?  If so the OP on an alternative forum had said to instantiate each connection and recordset/query independently. Although that would seem to be OK, that does seem to be A LOT of work to go back and clean up code.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rogue, no, I don't think so.  As my answer says though you should only ever need 1 recordset anyway, if you join tables properly and dump results to arrays.  This will be your biggest performance improvement.  As a note, I've used multiple recordsets with one open connection before no problems.  Sorry to hear you are still having problems, you learnt anything more about it?

Comment: I'm continuing to have problems with this issue.  And I'm unable to really pinpoint the problem, but I have some ideas.  The original coders did include the destroy in each close function.  The debug tool that was provided below works, but it slows my application down to a near crawl so I'm unable to use it to monitor effectively.  There is one thing I believe it could be - the main table for this application is nearly 335 fields large.  This is where practically every user writes and reads data from.  Even if the code doesn't call or write to each field the application still has to open a

Comment: large command to write/read data from that table - I'm assuming?

Comment: @rogue Are the SELECT queries on this table run with *, or do they explicitly select the required fields?  If you are opening a table with SELECT * FROM TABLE and it returns 1000 and there are a couple of closes not happening, this could cause the problems definitely.

Comment: There are some scripts that do use a * to select, but many of those have been converted to Views, and explicit required fields. I suspect, with the 1392 scripts in this application, that somewhere...I may have missed something, lol. Every script that I reviewed, I made sure that Closes were included for ever Open instance.

Comment: @rogue I would search the project for every select * on the table with 335 fields, and make sure they are all closing properly.  It only takes one leak on a popular page and this will clog everything up.  Let me know how you get on with this.  I'd be interested to see some of these pages, can you paste any entire pages?

Comment: I can most certainly share some code.  How do I markup the pasted code so it doesn't look all...retarded...

Comment: Also, I'm going to mark this answer as accepted.  I would like to share that with JB King also though!  The debug tool would work appplicably if my particular application didn't have a stroke when I ran it. I can see it's usefulness in other scenarios and environments.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using a memory monitoring tool to see how much memory fragmentation is happening?  My guess at a possible cause is that some object of a size is trying to be created but there isn't enough room in the memory to store it as one contiguous chunk.  Imagine needing room to store an object that would take 100 MB and while there may be several hundred megabytes free, the largest contiguous chunk is 90MB then this doesn't fit.

---

[Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) would be a tool where [Bernard's articles](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2006/07/22/Debugdiag-_2D00_-KB-Articles.aspx) may help in understanding how to use the tool.

Another thought is the question of how much string concatenation is there in the code?  I remember where I used to work had problems with doing a lot of string concatenation operations that sucked up memory that may be another idea to consider.

---

Yeah, I could see some shock at that kind of number the first few times you see it but then if you understand what the code is doing it may make sense for why so much space gets reserved right off the bat at times.

---

I haven't used that debug tool specifically but I did have a tool that took a snapshot of memory when pages were hung so I couldn't tell if there was a performance impact of the tool or not.  Course in my case I used a similar tool in 2004 so it has been a few years since I've had to research this kind of issue.

Comment: Any recommendations on a monitoring tool?  I can google them all day long - but would like something that is proven to at least have some help. I appreciate the input.

Comment: One thing I did note - And I'm not sure if this is normal - but once I started the Debug, before it actually does it's analysis you have to choose a process to attach to.  In the list it shows two instances of w3wp.exe - One of them has a Private Byte/Virtual Byte of 24mb/345mb.  Sounds normal.... But the other is 196mb/2048mb.  That's 2 Gig of virtual bytes!?  I somewhat heard the Snooki "waaaaah" once looking that number...

Comment: When I'm running the Debug tool, the entire web application slowly screeches to a near halt.  Page responses are very slow.  Is this a normal occurence while using this tool, in your experience?

Answer (score 2):

Just going to throw this in here, but this problem has taken a long time to solve.  Here's a breakdown of what we did:

1. We took all the inline SQL and made SQL Views, every `SELECT` statement is now handled with a `VIEW` first.
2. I took every single SQL INSERT and UPDATE (as much as I could without breaking the system) and put them into Stored Procedures.

   **#2 was the one item that really made the biggest difference**
3. Went through several thousand scripts, and ensured that variables were properly disposed of, and all the DB Open Connections were followed correctly with a Close Connection and same with Open/Close RecordSet.
4. One of the slow killers was doing something like:

   ID = Request.QueryString("ID)

at the top of the page.  Before redirecting, or closing a page, there is always a:

```
Set ID = Nothing
```

or the complete removal of the inference.