# When exactly am I required to set objects to nothing in classic asp?

Tags: object, asp-classic

On one hand the advice to always close objects is so common that I would feel foolish to ignore it (e.g. [VBScript Out Of Memory Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092814/vbscript-out-of-memory-error)).

However it would be equally foolish to ignore the wisdom of Eric Lippert, who appears to disagree:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx

I've worked to fix a number of web apps with OOM errors in classic asp.  My first (time consuming) task is always to search the code for unclosed objects, and objects not set to nothing.

But I've never been 100% convinced that this has helped. (That said, I have found it hard to pinpoint exactly what DOES help...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post by Eric is talking about *standalone VBScript files*, not classic ASP written in VBScript. See the comments, then Eric's own comment:

> Re: ASP -- excellent point, and one that I had not considered. In ASP it is sometimes very difficult to know where you are and what scope you're in.

So from this I can say that everything he wrote isn't relevant for classic ASP i.e. you should always Set everything to Nothing.

As for memory issues, I think that assigning objects (or arrays) to global scope like Session or Application is the main reason for such problems. That's the first thing I would look for and rewrite to hold only single identifider in Session then use database to manage the data.

Comment: What language do you think the majority of classic ASP is written in?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's not relevant, Eric was talking about standalone VBScript files. Will make it more clear in the post.

Comment: He's talking about the engine. As you yourself quote "it's sometimes very difficult ... what scope you're in". That's not the same as saying "when you exit a scope in ASP, what has been said above is incorrect"

Comment: Ok, thank you, that will be one of the first things I'll check next time.  Why would the advice differ between vbscript in asp and standalone vb?  I did look at the EL article again, but don't really get it.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox - If I'm remembering right, some of the scoping changes. Plus (and I'd argue more to the point) it's a lot easier for an object to chew up memory on a server when 300+ people are visiting a page vs. one person running a script on their desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Basically by setting a COM object to Nothing, you are forcing its terminator to run deterministically, which gives you the opportunity to handle any errors it may raise.

If you don't do it, you can get into a situation like the following:

- Your code raises an error
- The error isn't handled in your code and therefore ...
- other objects instantiated in your code go out of scope, and their terminators run
- one of the terminators raises an error
- and the error that is propagated is the one from the terminator going out of scope, masking the original error.

I do remember from the dark and distant past that it was specifically recommended to close ADO objects.  I'm not sure if this was because of a bug in ADO objects, or simply for the above reason (which applies more generally to any objects that can raise errors in their terminators).

And this recommendation is [often repeated](https://web.archive.org/web/20210211002355/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/top10/int1.shtml), though often without any credible reason. ("While ASP should automatically close and free up all object instantiations, it is always a good idea to explicitly close and free up object references yourself").

Comment: Yes, that's the advice I've read over and over again.  With no explanation other than the ASP garbage collector doesn't always work properly. Maybe I should accept the simplistic explanation.. but I'm curious :)

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox.  There isn't a garbage collector in ASP classic.

Comment: @Joe Classic ASP has garbage collection. Around the time of IIS 5 it was improved quite substantially.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that in the article, he's not saying you should never worry about setting objects to nothing - just that it should not be the default behaviour for every object in every script.

Though I do suspect he's a little too quick to dismiss the "I saw this elsewhere" method of coding behaviour, I'm willing to bet that there is a reason Eric *didn't* consider that has caused this to be passed along as a hard 'n' fast rule - dealing with junior programmers.

When you start looking more closely at the [Dreyfus model of skill acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition), you see that at the beginning levels of acquiring a new skill, learners need simple to follow recipes. They do not yet have the knowledge or ability to make the judgement calls Eric qualifies the recommendation with later on.

Think back to when you first started programming. Could you readily judge if you were "set[tting an] expensive objects to Nothing when you are done with them if you are done with them well before they go out of scope"? Did you really know which objects were expensive or when they truly went out of scope?

Thus, most entry level programmers are simply told "always set every object to Nothing when you are done with it" because it is within their grasp to understand and follow. Unfortunately, not many programmers take the time to self-educate, learn, and grow into the higher-level Dreyfus stages where you can use the more nuanced situational approach.

And then we come back to my earlier statement - even the best of us started out at that earlier stage, where we reflexively closed all objects because that was the best we were capable of. We left large bodies of code that people look at now, and project our current competence backwards to the earlier work and assume we did that for reasons we don't understand.

I've got to get going, but I hope to expand this a little futher...

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable to me. But it looks to me like even seasoned developers dish out this advice on a regular basis. Maybe it's the asp / standalone vb issue mentioned above.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Depends a lot on what you mean by "seasoned". I've known developers with 10 years experience, and I've known developers with one year experience repeated 10 years in a row.

Comment: I should probably add a note to self: I should expand more on lack of growth, and/or how less-than-modest developers may dish out truisms to those they feel are "inferior" - leading in part to treating everyone like they're at the novice stage of development.

Comment: Very true. I never stop learning more how much I don't know - or something like that